# Css div on hover effect - circle shaped border loading clockwise

Tags: jquery, html, css

I was wondering if anyone knows how to make an effect that many websites are using - on mouseover, effect that will look like the border around div is loading clockwise. I hope you can understand.

**GOAL:** When user places cursor over some div/img the border (for example circle, 2px, solid) should load from right to left, like an animation.

Here's the [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8hxzwmr2/).

In my example, there is not loading transition (animation). It is just simple hover effect provided by the next css code:

```
.myborder {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:lightgreen;
    transition:all .5s;
    -webkit-transition:all .5s;
    -moz-transition:all .5s;

}
.myborder:hover {
    border-radius:50%;
    border: 2px solid darkblue;
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: http://www.jqueryscript.net/loading/Circular-Percentage-Loader-Plugin-with-jQuery-Canvas-ClassyLoader.html take a look at this

Comment: It's not completely clear to me from your description how the animation should look.  Could you perhaps post an example of what kind of animated effect you're trying to achieve?